# Scala Generic function assuming type

Tags: scala

When trying to define a generic method `def f[T] (x:T) = x + 1` Scala gives below error

```
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
found   : Int(1)
required: String
   def f[T] (x:T) = x + 1
                        ^
```

The question is why Scala is assuming that it should be a `String`?

What if we want a function that can do `+1` to `Int`, `Char` and `String`. I know I can do something like below, but it would work only on `Int` and `Char`.

```
def f[T <% Int](x:T) = x + 1
```

So what's the reason of this error and how to handle it in generic way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is why Scala is assuming that it should be a String?

I can't guarantee this analysis, but it appears that Scala is applying the `Predef.any2stringadd()` implicit conversion to `x`, in an attempt to turn it into something that supports the `+` operator.

Here's a variant that will compile, and which demonstrates that implicit conversion:

```
scala> def f(x:Any) = { x + "1" }
f: (x: Any)String

scala> f("foo")
res3: String = foo1

scala> f(123)
res0: String = 1231

scala> f(classOf[String])
res2: String = class java.lang.String1
```

> What if we want a function that can do +1 to Int, Char and String.

What does it mean to add 1 to any of these values?

If you simply want to invoke the `+` operator, then you need to use the `match` operator to select different behaviors depending on the actual type. This is because, while the name `+` is used for both, there's no common behavior between strings and numbers.

On the other hand, perhaps you want to deal with numbers that can be provided as either strings or numeric values (in which case, why `Char`?). To make that work, you need an implicit function that converts `Any` to a number.

```
scala> implicit def any2int(x:Any) : Int = { x.toString.toInt }
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
any2int: (x: Any)Int

scala> def f(x:Any) : Int = { x + 1 }
f: (x: Any)Int

scala> f(123)
res0: Int = 124

scala> f("123")
res1: Int = 124
```

Comment: I respectfully disagree that "there's no common behavior between strings and numbers"; the concept of a `Monoid` exists for a reason.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the function will always be Int as I assume so it should be that the compiler choose Int but why String.